# Как отсортировать элементы каждого столбца массива без использования numpy и pandas?

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка

Задание звучит так:

"**Отсортировать элементы каждого столбца двумерного массива чисел (n х m) по не убыванию значений элементов.**"

```
import random
n, m = 3, 3
A = [[random.randint(0, 10) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

У меня есть несколько потенциально верных вариантов решения, но все они не рабочие(

### 1.

```
for j in range(m):
    for i in range(n):
        if A[i][j] > A[i + 1][j]:
            A[i][j], A[i + 1][j] = A[i + 1][j], A[i][j]
```

### 2

Через транспонирование => sort/sorted

```
trasnpA = list(zip(*A))
for i in range(3):
    sorted(A[i])
print(trasnpA)
print(list(zip(*trasnpA)))
```

### 3

Через sort/sorted c ключом

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: и что получается в результате этих трех вариантов? какие-то проблемы?

Comment: Все они нерабочие. Вроде в правильном направлении двигаюсь, но ничего не получается

Comment: а что с транспонированием не так?

Comment: В варианте 1 у вас же выход за пределы массива получается? Почему вы сразу не пишете суть проблем, а мы должны догадываться обо всём?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут действительно проще всего решать через транспонирование.

```
import random

A = [[random.randint(0, 10) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]

A_transposed = list(zip(*A))

A_transposed_sorted = [sorted(row) for row in A_transposed]

A_sorted = [list(x) for x in list(zip(*A_transposed_sorted))]

print(A) # [[9, 2, 2, 4], [9, 6, 5, 0], [4, 10, 0, 5], [9, 6, 3, 0]]

print(A_sorted) # [[4, 2, 0, 0], [9, 6, 2, 0], [9, 6, 3, 4], [9, 10, 5, 5]]
```

Или в одну строчку

```
A_sorted = [list(x) for x in list(zip(*[sorted(row) for row in list(zip(*A))]))]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
n, m = 3, 3
A = [[random.randint(0, 10) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

def matrix_column_sort(matrix):
    transpose_matrix = [list(row) for row in zip(*matrix)]
    sorted_transpose_matrix = list(map(sorted, transpose_matrix))
    sorted_matrix = [list(row) for row in zip(*sorted_transpose_matrix)]
    return sorted_matrix

print(A)
print(matrix_column_sort(A))
```